# Is there a reverse proxy that will prevent CSRF attacks?

Tags: security, proxy, csrf, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to use a reverse proxy to prevent XSS/CSRF attacks? For simplicity, consider a simple internal site, accessed by trusted users, with two endpoints,

```
/home.html --> basic HTML page
/api/might_be_dangerous?... --> not security-proofed over all possible parameters
```

`home.html` will only access `/api/might_be_dangerous` with safe arguments, but an external site might not.

Is it possible to use a reverse proxy to

1. Set a cookie when `home.html` is visited
2. Check the cookie when `/api/might_be_dangerous` is accessed

and whatever else is necessary to prevent XSS/CSRF attacks? I think I could probably write one using Flask and so forth, it just seems that having it exposed via a reverse proxy would be a nice, reusable abstraction. Of course, one would need to configure which endpoints (`home.html` in this case) can set the cookie, and which require it, but this doesn't seem to be a technical hurdle.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to use a reverse proxy to prevent XSS/CSRF attacks?

In the general case no. Addressing these issues requires knowledge from the application.

The proper way to prevent HTML-injections (the most common cause of XSS) is to HTML-escape output when creating pages. A proxy can't do that because it only gets the complete page without knowing which bits were variables that needed escaping.

The proper way to prevent XSRF is to require a secret value be submitted as non-persistent request data that matches up with the persistent request data. A proxy can't do that because it doesn't know how the client will be creating the request, to have secret data added to it.

There are, nonetheless, reverse proxies that **try** to prevent CSRF and XSS attacks. This is a typical feature of a Web Application Firewall (WAF). Sometimes they even sort-of work. But do anything outside a narrow range of the behaviour they expect and you won't be covered.

For example, a WAF might filter submitted `<` characters in form data as an attempt to prevent HTML injection. But if your app is submitting non-form content such as JSON then likely this won't be caught. And if your application actually needs to be able to accept `<` characters in input, it'll break. And either way, other forms of injection (eg HTML attribute injection or JS injection) wouldn't be affected.

Similarly, a WAF might inject an `<input type="hidden" name="csrftoken" value="..."/>` into `<form method="POST">` elements produced by the application, and check that a `csrftoken` is supplied in the POST that comes back from that. But the moment you do anything clever with JS/AJAX on the client side, that's not going to work, and you won't be protected if you forgot to make the form POST-only.

So although a reverse proxy such as a WAF might be of some use in blocking attacks (and typically more use in acting as a passive intrusion detector), it's inherently unreliable, and typically needs a bunch of configuration and tuning to work without breaking your apps, which in turn requires a level of understanding of those apps and the threats against. At which point you're often better off putting the fixes for those threats in the app itself where it better fits.

Answer (score 1):

Setting and checking the cookie will not protect against [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) because if the user has your website open on their first browser tab, but is manipulated into opening the attacker's site in their second tab, the attackers site could make a request to `yoursite.com/api/might_be_dangerous` and the cookie set from your home page will be passed. Under CSRF your `api/might_be_dangerous` request would only be dangerous if executed in the context of the current user, so this implies the user is logged into your site and the attacker's site causes the request to be made unwillingly by the authenticated user. The way to prevent this is to include a token unique to the session in a hidden field that is sent by `home.html` and validated by the `api/might_be_dangerous` code. See: [General Recommendation: Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern)

I'm not sure how you aim to prevent CSRF and [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) with a reverse proxy. Please update your answer to explain. Thanks.